# Update a local branch with the updated changes I pulled into my local main branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I'm new to using Git, and we have a remote main set up and I have pulled the updated changes into my local main, my question is how do I update the local branches that I will create with those updated changes?

Can I do

```
git pull origin main
```

in the local branch or should I switch to the local branch and do

```
git merge main
```

on the local branch?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to update a local branch `mybranch` from the remote `main`, you do not need a local `main`. Indeed, if you are following good git flow practices, and merging to `main` via pull requests, you should have no local `main` at all.

Just work on `mybranch`. From time to time `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/main` or `git rebase origin/main`, to acquire the latest state of remote `main`.